# my project with python thread, raspberrypi HC-SR04 and Flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, raspberry-pi

```
def det_rec(self):
    try :
        while True:
            gpio.output(trig, False)
            time.sleep(0.5)

            gpio.output(trig, True)
            time.sleep(0.00001)

            gpio.output(trig, False)

            while gpio.input(echo) == 0 :
                pulse_start = time.time()
            while gpio.input(echo) == 1 :
                pulse_end = time.time()

            pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
            self.distance = pulse_duration * 17000
            self.distance = round(distance, 2)
            return self.distance
    except :
        gpio.cleanup()
```

this function not return distance.

The result is None, I don't know what to do.

How can I fix this code ?.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the try / except statement, if an exception occurs your method does not run any 'return' statement and in python that makes it return None.

A little extra hint: You should avoid to store distance as a member variable (self.distance) and return it, it might be confusing to do both.